# How to properly use SET DATEFIRST function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to set the date as Monday and then order the results by the 'day of the week' starting with Monday.  Unfortunately, it seems as if the DATEFIRST function doesn't do anything and my output keeps on thinking Friday is the first day of the week.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT FirstName, LastName, HireDate, datename(dw,HireDate) AS 'Day of the Week'
FROM Faculty
ORDER BY datename(dw,HireDate);
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
Lynda   Baker   1989-09-15  Friday
Tim Stewart 2000-09-15  Friday
John    Puckett 1989-09-15  Friday
Maria Lynn  Kessler 2003-09-15  Monday
Leo Dubray  2001-09-15  Saturday
Jamie   Zipay   2001-01-07  Sunday
Michele Malott  2005-09-15  Thursday
Robin   Schwartz    1999-09-15  Wednesday
```

Anyone know how I can use DATEFIRST or any other function that will allow me to sort the day of the week starting with Monday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to order by `DATEPART` not `DATENAME`.

`DATEPART` returns an integer, dependant on the `DATEFIRST` setting. `DATENAME` returns a string with the day of the week.

The string 'Monday' will always come after 'Friday' as it is alphabetically sorted.